# Strange performance of SELECT COUNT(1)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, count

I have a select query with some complex joins and `where` conditions and it takes ~9seconds to execute.

Now, the strange thing is if I wrap the query with `select count(1)` the execution time will increase dramatically.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM 
(
    SELECT .... -- initial query, executes ~9s
) 
-- executes 1min
```

That's very strange to me, since I would expect an opposite result - the sql-server engine should be smart enough to optimize the inner query execution (for instance, do not execute nested queries in the `select` clause, etc).

And that's what execution plans comparison shows! It says it should be **74%** to **26%** (the former is initial query and latter is wrapped with `select count(1)`).

But that's not what really happens.

Idk if I should post the query itself, since it's rather large (if you need it then just let me know in comments).

Thaks you!)

Comment: Can... we see the plans?

Comment: When you deal with nested queries the inner one usually affects the results of the 'parent' select clause. So inner queries should be executed as well before counting the results

Comment: I guess nested queries in `select` clause will no way affect the result of `count(*)` or `count(1)`, am I not correct?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, as I said the queries are quite complex, so it's really difficult to show them as images. Anyway, here's the 1st http://i.imgur.com/n411yx0.png and the second http://i.imgur.com/DP4Q3Dt.png (this one is not really comprehensible, but...).

Comment: Do you see that `MISSING INDEX` suggestion?

Comment: yes, off course. How does this relate to my question?

Comment: what happens if you remove the outer select and push the COUNT(1) into the nested SELECT

Comment: basically the same thing

Answer (score 1):

When you use `count(1)` you no longer need all the columns.

This means that SQL Server can consider different execution plans using narrower indexes that do not cover all the columns used in the `SELECT` list of the original query.

Generally this should of course lead to a leaner, faster, execution plan however looks like in this case you were unlucky and it didn't.

Probably you will find a node with a large discrepancy between actual and estimated rows - this kind of thing will propagate up in the plan and can lead to sub optimal choices of strategy for other sub trees (e.g. sub optimal join orderings or algorithms)